# How do I obtain the value that caused any() to return True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, any

When I call the `any()` function, it returns only `True` or `False`. If it returns `True`, how can I obtain the element that caused it to return `True`?

```py
all = ['azeri', 'english', 'japan', 'india', 'indonesia']
lg = 'from japan'
lgn = lg.split()
if any(word in lgn for word in all):
      print(word)
```

In this case, I'd like to obtain the word `japan`. This code, as written, just returns `NameError: name 'word' is not defined.`

Comment: Beware: naming your variable with `all` shadows a built-in function.

Comment: why not just: `for word in lgn: print(word) if word in all else None` ? in your example `word` is defined only inside the `any` call so you cannot access it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that `any` returns `True` or `False` based on the fact that condition matches for any element in the iterable. But this is not how you extract the element which satisfied the condition

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any

> any(iterable)
>   Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False.

In your case, since the condition is met, the print statement will execute as below. But since `word` is only within the scope of the generator inside `any`, you get the error `NameError: name 'word' is not defined.`
Also you should not name your variable `all` since it will shadow the builtin 
[all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

```
In [15]: all = ['azeri', 'english', 'japan', 'india', 'indonesia'] 
    ...: lg = 'from japan' 
    ...: lgn = lg.split() 
    ...: if any(word in lgn for word in all): 
    ...:     print('condition met') 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
condition met
```

If you want to find the list of words satisfying the condition, you should use a for-loop in say a list-comprehension

```
all_words = ['azeri', 'english', 'japan', 'india', 'indonesia']
lg = 'from japan'
lgn = lg.split()

#Find words which are present in lgn
res = [word for word in all_words if word in lgn]

print(res)
```

The output will be `['japan']`

Comment: This is a good solution, but I want a `string` to be the output. So I would make a code like,
`for word in lgn:
     if word in all_words:
         print(word)
     else:
         None;` like what @0x2bad said

Comment: Okay, they you can just print the elements of `res` in a for loop @ArmandDwi

Answer (score 3):

As per your requirement i think, you should be using just `filter` instead of any. The below code should work.

```
all = ['azeri', 'english', 'japan', 'india', 'indonesia']
lg = 'from japan'
lgn = lg.split()

print(list(filter(lambda word: word in lgn, all)))
```